# construct active directory tree of OUs and number of computers

Tags: python, active-directory

Sorry if this question is kind of noob - but finding the right docs for AD is a bit hard...

I need to export the entire "tree stucture" of an active-directory - so that in each junction in the tree I have the number of computers.

example:

```
DC-main(100)
|
--- OU - rnd (50)
|    |
|     ----- team1 (30)
|     ----- team2 (20)
----OU - marketing (50)
```

Let's assume I have access to the domain controller (or to the forest root?) - can I have something nice in order to get this tree?

Or do I have to iterate the entire active directory and build it one DC/OU at the time (which is not very scalable on large ADs)

Implementation is in python but I'm sticking to the general concept here - so feel free to offer solutions in any language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is going to be to iterate over each OU and construct the view. All of the DCs in a given domain will return the same data so you don't need to visit each DC.

There is an attribute in AD, `msds-Approx-Immed-Subordinates` that will give you an /estimate/ for about how many objects are under each OU. This is a constructed attribute, though, so you will still need to visit each OU to request the data.

Comment: And I don't need to go down the "hierarchy tree" to get to all the OUs? I can just get a list of all AUs?

Comment: It's a constructed attribute so you can't retrieve it as part of a subtree search result.